# can only concatenate list (not "Point") to list In adding and subtracting points in python

Tags: python, python-class

I am trying to perform the following task :
For two points  (1,1)+(2,2)=(1+2,1+2)

I have this code executed :

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return [self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y]
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return [self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y]
```

when I try to run the following piece of code, it says:

```
from functools import reduce
def add_sub_results(points):
    points = [Point(*point) for point in points]
    return [str(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, points)), 
            str(reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, points))]
```

it returns

```
 return [str(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, points)), 
      5             str(reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, points))]
      6 

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Point") to list
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [more info on `reduce`](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/). Specifically you can use `add` and `sub` from the `operator` module instead of lambdas. In fact, for the first case, Python already has a built-in `sum` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `__add__()` and `__sub__()` methods of your `Point` class should be:

```py
class Point(object):
    ...
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y) #<-- MODIFIED THIS

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y) #<-- MODIFIED THIS
```